# Differences between wcfrun32.exe and wfica32.exe

Tags: citrix, xenapp

What are the differences between wcfrun32.exe and wfica32.exe

Answer (score 2):

Wcfrun32 is an agent that is always running in the background. It displays the receiver icon in the bottom right of your screen in the notification area, and manages updates, settings, etc. wfica32 is only started when you make a remote HDX connection to a Citrix server - it presents the remote Citrix session to the user.

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand, **wfcrun32.exe** is the connection manager which manages all ICA connections.

**wfica32.exe** represents each connection. Each virtual channel would have a wfica32.exe process associated with it which contains drivers that manage your connection and de-multiplex the virtual channel data from the ICA stream.